# SQL - Min difference between two integer fields

Tags: sql

How I can get min difference between two integer fields(`value_0 - value`)?
`value_0 >= value` always

```
value_0 | value
-------------------  
    15  |  10
    12  |  10
    15  |  11
    11  |  11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(value_0-value) as MinDiff
FROM TableName
WHERE value_0>=value
```

With the sample data you have given,
Output is `0`. (11-11)

See demo in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c83bd/5).

Read more about `MIN()` [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
select min(value_0 - value)
from table t;
```

This is pretty basic SQL.  *If* you want to see other values on the same row as the minimum, use `order by` and choose one row:

```
select (value_0 - value)
from table t
order by (value_0 - value)
limit 1;
```

The `limit 1` works in some databases for getting one row.  Others use `top 1` in the `select` clause.  Or `fetch first 1 rows only`.  Or even something else.